# Unused global options error for simple document class?

Tags: warnings

I've already looked on stack exchange and found no clear answer that addresses my problem. I have an error **"Unused global option(s): [10]."** and after a modification **"Unused global option(s): [letter,10]."** I have no reason to believe an article can't use 10, 11 or 12 pt font, and I also want the page sizes to be U.S. letter which is why the letter option is there.

It was working completely fine, then randomly after some point I started getting this error when compiling.

```
\documentclass[letter,10]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{Images}}

\title{test title}
\author{test name}
\date{September 20, 2017}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\abstract{
test abstract
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Try it with option `10pt` instead `10`.

Comment: And use `letterpaper` instead `letter`

Comment: Alright those suggestions helped. I still see no way of verifying that the page size is as I want it to be in texmaker, but I haven't gotten any errors so I'll assume it is for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `article` class options are `letterpaper` and `10pt` not `letter` and `10`, and actually both of these are the class defaults so you could just omit the optional argument, and use

```
\documentclass{article}
```

Note the unused option warning is a warning, not an error (TeX does not stop with an error message).